# Tweet to tweeter automatically using cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to tweet in tweeter app without his intend using cordova.
I have tried below plugin:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Below is the example how you can tweet using plugin. The problem is it gives a popup (or confirmation box) to user before it post to tweeter. I want it should get posted without user intend.

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaTwitter('Message via Twitter')
```

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detail Blog :  http://sforsuresh.in/cordova-twitter-post-on-behalf-of-user

Somehow i have achieve using "[codebird.js](https://github.com/jublo/codebird-js)" library

```
    var cd = new Codebird;
    var storage = window.localStorage;
    cd.setToken(storage.getItem("oauth_token"),storage.getItem("oauth_token_secret"));
    cd.__call("statuses_update", { status: "This is my first tweet." }, function(reply,rate,err) {
        console.log("xxx"+JSON.stringify(reply));
    });
```

The above code will tweet directly without user intent.
You need to include js before you write above code:

```
<script src="js/codebird.js"></script>
```

For getting user token and secret, I am using "[cordova-twitter3-connect-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-twitter3-connect-plugin)" plugin and can call below function on "onDeviceReady()" to get and store in localstorage.

```
function setusertoken() {
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("oauth_token") != null) {
        return false;
    }
    TwitterConnect.login(
      function(result) {
        var storage = window.localStorage;
        storage.setItem("oauth_token", result.token);
        storage.setItem("oauth_token_secret", result.secret);
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log('[Login] - Error logging in: ' + error);
      }
    );      
}
```